# Run jar file without admin rights

Tags: windows, jar, console, admin

I have a runnable jar file, that I start with

```
java -jar myFile.jar
```

on Windows. A customer stated that he had problems starting the application (which is this jar file wrapped into an executable). I have the suspicion that it has something to do with admin rights. So I'd like to run my jar file without admin rights for testing purposes (because this way I get the `System.out/err` which helps greatly for debugging).

I realize that I can just create a non-admin account and start the application there, but **I'd like to know if there is a way to specifically start a jar from an admin account so that it doesn't have admin rights in the console.** Or alternatively: Is there a way to open up a console that has no admin rights from an admin account?

The customer uses Windows XP, so this is the operating system that I can use. (Although if you know something in a newer Windows like Win7, I appreciate it if you would tell me too).

EDIT: To clarify: I am looking for something like this

```
java -jar -runWithoutAdminRights myFile.jar
```

or

```
start /runWithoutAdminRights java -jar myFile.jar
```

or a way to open up a non-admin console from an admin account.

Comment: I will say that it's not likely.

Comment: @ShaneHsu Looks like it... ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Runas command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490994.aspx) definitely looks like the way to go.

I believe the way to go about this would be to first check the trust level options available to you:

`runas /showtrustlevels`

You should get something like the following:

```
C:\Windows\system32>runas /showtrustlevels
The following trust levels are available on your system:
0x20000 (Basic User)
```

You would then take the value for "Basic User" and run something like the following to start java:

`runas /trustlevel:0x20000 "java -jar myFile.jar"`

Comment: I **knew** it is possible. I will test this out on monday. :)

Comment: Works perfectly. Although on some computers I just get "Basic User" without the ID. Is there a way to achieve this on those systems?

Comment: Hm, how can I give the bounty to you as well? :/

Comment: Interesting to get "Basic User" without any id.. From what I can tell, the 0x20000 appears to be a standard. Perhaps running with /trustlevel:0x20000 will work even if, for whatever reason, it's not defined with /showtrustlevels on a given system. As for the bounty I have no idea, I'm just glad I could help =)

Comment: I can confirm that 0x20000 works even if it is not shown. At least on the machines I am working with. Thanks again. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the below steps:

> 1. Log in as the Administrator
> 2. Open the command line
> 3. Go to System32 folder (cd C:/Windows/System32)
> 4. execute: runas /user:computer_domain_name\user1 cmd

You will be asked to provide the user1's password. Afterwards a new command line opens with the user1's rights.

I have tried it and it worked.

In conclusion you can write a very simple batch which performs the steps 2,3,4 automatically so that when you click it, a command line will open with the rights of another user.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will test this out on monday. It looks very promising.

Comment: Works good, but I don't want to create another account. Eitherway, you have given me a useful solution that correctly answers the question and shall be rewarded. ;)

Answer (score 0):

edit registry is best way to run jar file with administrator automatically.
is easy if you have setup for java application.
go to following path in registry:
    `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers`
create a key(String Value) with following specification:
    `ValueName: java path+javaw.exe(example c:\program files\java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe)`
    `ValueData: "WINXPSP3 RUNASADMIN"`

Now All Jar Files Runs to Administartor

Comment: I actually like to run it as **non-admin** from an administrator account, not the other way around. Also I only want to run a single jar that way, not all of the all the times. So changing the registry is not really an option.